# Compile a ccs script file within c# application

Tags: c#

I have a script file(`.ccs`) with some functions that creates an excel file with data. 
How can I compile this file within a c# function? I also have to pass some parameters to it.

I can't find any information on the internet about it. This is the path to the file.

```
string ccsFile = "C:\\Templates\\myCCSFile.ccs";
```

Comment: Are you talking about CS-Script? There's information here about it: http://www.csscript.net/

Comment: I can't find anything out about `ccs` scripts so I can't provide insight into the question as asked. That said, one way to create an excel file with C# is to use the COM automation library. You can find information about that here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CS script - the comment above will work - for C# you need to take a look at the `CSharpCodeProvider` - it generally looks like that:

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,SourceString);
```

The trick is to have some entry point afterward that you find and then invoke trough reflection.